# React Native: Exception thrown while executing UI block

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator

I'm building an iOS react-native app, and I'm currently using the react-native-swipe-card package to build "tinder" like swipe cards for my app. The app works fine however when I go to swipe a card left or right, and let it go while it's halfway off the screen I'm getting the following error:

ExceptionsManager.js:71 Exception thrown while executing UI block: -[NSNull floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1075b5130

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem while calling `setValue(param)` on an instance of Animated.Value, because `param` was **undefined** by mistake

Comment: See this solution it worked for me: https://github.com/meteor-factory/react-native-tinder-swipe-cards/issues/87

Comment: Do not post an image when text would suffice.

Comment: I have solved a simillar problem here for Victory Native: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73302893/614065

Answer (score 7):

As @Peuchele commented, I was getting this same error, and the reason it was happening was because I passed a value into an Animated View that was undefined.

So, to clarify, make sure any values you pass into a component using an `Animated.Value` is not undefined.

The specific code I found at fault was:

```
const { value } = props;

this.state = {
  translateYValue: new Animated.Value(value),
};
```

And `props.value` was `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when passing an `undefined` to the `defaultSource` prop of an `Image`.

```
<Image
    style={styles.imageStyle}
    source={someImageSource}
    defaultSource={imageFallback}
/>
```

When `imageFallback` is undefined, I got this error.

Previous answers mention passing an `undefined` into `Animated.Value`.  Given that my experience is via a different component, this error probably means you're passing an `undefined` somewhere.

I found the culprit by commenting out varying lines of code to see what caused the error to appear.  Tedious but effective.

Answer (score 1):

This exception was thrown for me on passing a null value as the html value to WebView.  The *source* cannot be a null.

```
<WebView
  originWhitelist={['*']}
  source={{ html: summary }}
  style={[styles.webView, { height: webViewHeight }]}
  scalesPageToFit={false}
  useWebKit
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or make sure the value being passed is not NAN

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add `@objc` above the block in native code where you define the property.