# Exception thrown while executing UI block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-chart-kit

I'm having an issue with expo and react-native-chart-kit.
See screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Expo SDK: 36.0.0

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native: Exception thrown while executing UI block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43822984/react-native-exception-thrown-while-executing-ui-block)

Comment: @TrueTiem thanks, actually downgrading react-native-svg to `"9.13.3` worked, I was using 11.0.1

Comment: Hi. Please do not post code as image. Consider posting your solution as an answer.